# GraphQL query is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, graphql, hotchocolate

I'm using graphQL hot chocolate and need to fetch data.
I need to fetch data from Template that has Specs and in spec it contains AttributeType.
when i try to query the data, template and spec has values but AttributeType is null that should not be.
here are my entities:

Template

```
public         long            Id          { get; set; }
public         bool            IsDeleted   { get; set; }
public         string          Name        { get; set; }
public         long            SpecId      { get; set; }
public virtual List<Spec>      Specs       { get; set; }
```

Spec

```
public long           Id              { get; set; }
public int            Position        { get; set; }
public string         Label           { get; set; }
public bool           IsDeleted       { get; set; }

public virtual AttributeType  AttributeType   { get; set; }
public         long           AttributeTypeId { get; set; }

public Template Template    { get; set; }
public long?    TemplateId  { get; set; }
```

and finally AttributeType

```
public         long            Id          { get; set; }
public         string          Description { get; set; }
public         string          Format      { get; set; }
```

I used Dataloader and resolver to fetch the data

```
[Authorize]
[GraphQLType( typeof(TemplateObjectType) )]
public  Task<Template> GetTemplateById( long id, TemplateDataLoader dataLoader, CancellationToken cancellationToken )
  => dataLoader.LoadAsync( id, cancellationToken );
```

```
public class TemplateObjectType: ObjectType<Template>
{
    protected override void Configure( IObjectTypeDescriptor<Template> descriptor )
    {
      descriptor.Field( x => x.Specs)
                .ResolveWith<TemplateResolver>( r => r.GetSpecsAsync( default, default, default ) );
    }
}

public async Task<IReadOnlyList<Spec>> GetSpecAsync(
    [Parent] Template template,
    SpecDataLoader dataLoader,
    CancellationToken   cancellationToken)
        => await dataLoader.LoadAsync(template.Id, cancellationToken);
    
protected override async Task<ILookup<long, Spec>> LoadGroupedBatchAsync( IReadOnlyList<long> keys, CancellationToken cancellationToken )
{
    var result = await _dbContext.Templates
                                 .Where( template => keys.Contains( template.Id ) )
                                 .Select( x => new {
                                                       TemplateId= x.Id,
                                                       x.Specs
                                                   } )
                                 .ToListAsync( cancellationToken: cancellationToken );

    var final = result
                .Select(x => x.Specs.Select(c => new
                                                      {
                                                        x.TemplateId,
                                                        Spec= c
                                                      }))
                .SelectMany(x => x)
                .ToLookup(x => x.TemplateId, x => x.Spec);

    return final;
}
```

When I query GetTemplateById I get the result but **AttributeType** is null which shouldn't be, here is a sample of the query:

```
"data": {
    "templatebyId": {
        "name": "test",
        "specs": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "position": 0,
                "label": "price",
                "templateId": 1,
                "attributeType": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default EF tries to optimize the amount of data fetched from the database. As your code is now, the attributes are not loaded.

You should either include the `attributes` in this call, or omit the `ToListAsync` to have EF determine you'll need the data in a later stage.

```
var result = await _dbContext.Templates
                               .Where( template => keys.Contains( template.Id ) )
                               .Select( x => new {
                                                   TemplateId= x.Id,
                                                   x.Specs
                                                 } )
                               .ToListAsync( cancellationToken: cancellationToken );
```

Using [Include/ThenInclude](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.theninclude?view=efcore-6.0) will tell the framework to include the data:

```
var result = await _dbContext.Templates
                           .Where( template => keys.Contains( template.Id ) )
                           .Include(prop => prop.Specs)
                           .ThenInclude(spec => spec.AttributeType) 
                           .Select( x => new {
                                               TemplateId= x.Id,
                                               x.Specs
                                             } )
                           .ToListAsync( cancellationToken: cancellationToken );
```